# Magento 1.9 use Paypal Express order status is wrong!

Tags: magento-1.9

i use paypal express payment,after paid the order status become "pending" from "processing",[image]
this is "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" picture

[image]
please help me ~~thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try these solution,Hope It's work for you.**

> Try to set "**Transfer Cart Line Items**" to **No** under configuration->payment methods->PayPal Express Checkout
>
> If it does works for you then please try below one.

**Other Solution :-**

> The latest PayPal integration changed the order processing schema (from PayPal side). Now there are no results being returned to Magento after you successfully paid for the order. Instead store owner should configure PayPal IPN feature.
>
> Unfortunately the link to configure PayPal IPN is no longer on the Magento wiki. Here's the link to the PayPal docs (which is the majority of the config required): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/
>
> Magento IPN receiver would be something like: http://www.yoursitename.com/index.php/paypal/ipn/index/ - use your real domain. That should go into the Notification URL config in your PP acc.
>
> Found On :-
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252427/magento-1-7-0-2-pending-payment-status-after-successful-payment-in-paypal

Comment: thank you @Randhir Yadav , i find this problem : my website ipn interface request must have a key if this key set in admin panel ,if not set ,interface return 503 error.  if i disable this configure in admin panel, ipn interface  don't need this key.  thanks agian~~